# How is a plugin like facebook login plugin build up?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, html, plugins

How does the plugin communicate with the facebook server without exposing too much information.

I would like to know how I can build myself a plugin that would communicate between the website it's installed on and my website.

My knowledge is limited to HTML5, CSS3, PHP5, Javascript and some Jquery.
I realise that there could be alot of ways, I was just wandering if you could point me in the right direction, or give me an idea. (: thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [easyXDM framework](http://easyxdm.net), which allows you to do this quite easily, and if you have a chance, read [Third Party JavaScript](http://thirdpartyjs.com/), which explains what you want to do in detail.

Some years ago, I wrote about [this topic on scriptjunkie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff800814.aspx), it's as relevant now as then (although more browsers support postMessage now).

Answer (score -1):

1. Create an application on developers.facebook.com
2. Download the facebook SDK for PHP since this is what you know (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php)
3. Read their guideline on how to implement login (it is easy and helpful)
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/

This is a sample PHP function that you can build on:

```
function facebook_login()
{
    $user = new user();

    // Call Facebook API
    if (!class_exists('FacebookApiException')) {
        require_once ('facebook.php');
    }

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
    ));
    $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($fbuser) {
        try {
            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $me = $facebook->api('/me'); //user
            $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        }
        catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo error_log($e);
            return;
        }
    }

    // redirect user to facebook login page if empty data or fresh login requires
    if (!$fbuser) {
        $loginUrl = $facebook - getLoginUrl(array(
            'redirect_uri' => $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],
            false
        ));
        $logout = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
        echo $loginUrl;
        return;
    }

    // user details
    $user->name = $me['name'];
    $user->email = $me['email'];
    $user->fbid = $uid;

    // Check user id in your database
    $user->selectbyfbid();
    if ($user->database->rows > 0) {
        // User exist, Show welcome back message
        // User is now connected, log him in
    }
    else {
        // User is new, Show connected message and store info in our Database
        // Insert user into Database.
        $user->insert_fb();
    }

    $_SESSION["access_token"] = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    login_user($user);
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="LoadingAnimate();">
    <div class="fb-login-button" 
        onlogin="javascript:CallAfterLogin();" 
        data-width="600" data-max-rows="1" 
        data-show-faces="false" 
        scope="publish_stream,email,publish_actions,offline_access">
```

JavaScript code:

```
function CallAfterLogin(){
    FB.login(function(response) {       
        if (response.status === "connected") 
        {
            LoadingAnimate(); //show a waiting gif or whatever
            FB.api('/me', function(data) {
                if(data.email == null)
                {
                    //Facbeook user email is empty, you can check something like this.
                    ResetAnimate();

                }else{
                    AjaxResponse();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
function AjaxResponse()
{
    var myData = 'connect=1&action=fb_login';
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/process_user.php",
        dataType:"html",
        data:myData,
        cache: false,
        success:function(response){
            if(target.length > 1)
                window.location.href = target;
            else
                location.reload();
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        //$("#results").html('<fieldset style="color:red;">'+thrownError+'</fieldset>'); //Error
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this helps you start!

Comment: Does not address the question.

Comment: @SeanKinsey you are 100% correct ... I have no idea WTH was I thinking :D